# Как из конфига получить данные

Tags: php

Есть функция

```
protected function getcates($nom){
$part = "snippet";
$js=file_get_contents('https://ссылка.ру/123');
if(preg_match('#push\((?<json>.*?)\);#',$js,$match))
....
```

Как заменить `https://ссылка.ру/123` чтобы данные (`123`) брались из конфиг-файла?
`https://ссылка.ру/{$this->config["myurl"]}` - не работает.
В продолжении функции, в строке `$this->url = "{$this->config["myurl"]}..............` - работает.
Спасибо!

Comment: `file://path/to/your/file`?  `/path/to/yor/file`?  http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Я не верно сформулировал, $js=file_get_contents('https://ссылка.ру/{$this->config["myurl"]}');

Comment: {$this->config["myurl"]} не работает   :(

Comment: Но мы же не знаем, что такое `$this->config`. Это массив? Что лежит в нём по ключу myurl?

Comment: Нет, это не массив

Comment: А что? Объект? ArrayAccess? Давайте не будем играть в угадайку - добавьте необходимую информацию в вопрос

Comment: по ключу myurl лежит 123

Comment: Попробуйте то, что уже пробовали, но с двойными кавычками

Comment: vp_arth, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Строковый тип данных](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php)

> **Замечание:** В отличие от синтаксиса двойных кавычек и heredoc, переменные и управляющие последовательности для специальных символов,
>   заключенных в одинарные кавычки, не обрабатываются.

Чтобы использовать данные из переменных в строках используйте:

- Строки в двойных кавычках: `"https://ссылка.ру/{$this->config["myurl"]}"`
- HEREDOC синтаксис:

```
$url = <<<TEXT
https://ссылка.ру/{$this->config["myurl"]}
TEXT;
```

- Конкатенацию: `"https://ссылка.ру/" . $this->config["myurl"]`
- Специализированные [функции](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php) форматирования: `sprintf('https://ссылка.ру/%s', $this->config["myurl"])`