# Как подставить переменную вместо цифры в названии фото?

Tags: php

Фотка называется poker1. Нужно, чтобы фото выводилось, когда в переменную прилетит единица. `$roll = rand(1, 6);
        echo "You rolled a $roll";
        echo "<br>";
        echo '<img src="img\poker1.jpg" alt="">';`

Comment: `echo '<img src="img\poker'.$roll.'.jpg" alt="">';` Если есть только одно фото то лучше делать через `if`

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/640448/176064

Comment: классно.  спасибо))

Comment: Изучаю php по книге "PHP/MySQL для начинающих" Энди Харрис. 2005 год, а там старые стандарты... не все приведенные примеры работают

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто заменить статику на переменную:

```
$roll = rand(1, 6);
echo "You rolled a $roll";
echo "<br>";
echo '<img src="img\poker'.$roll.'.jpg" alt="">';
```